# MVC compare 2 values into model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc application in asp.net. In my C# model i need to compare 2 values and then if one is bigger than the other show a message. Is this even achieveble, i am a begginer at this whole c# mvc applications

```
[UIHint("ValuesModel")]
public ValuesModel LowValue { get; set; }
[UIHint("ValuesModel")]
public ValuesModel HighValue { get; set; }
```

I need to be able to set LowValue to be smaller every time and if it's not the case show an error message, also i need to style after that via css the higgest value so i am guessing maybe i can pass a class or something so i can access it via javascript ( i used to do this in php ). Please help me i am stuck on this.

Comment: Look at using a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[GreaterThan]` or similar validation attribute to give you both server and client side validation

Comment: You just download the nuget package and add [GreaterThan("LowValue")] to your property. But I have just noticed that your properties are complex objects, (in which case it would not work) so how would you compare them anyway?

Comment: If you want to compare properties inside `LowValue` and `HighValue` classes then as a quick fix, try first validating inside controller and if the criteria doesn't match then fail the ModelState validation by adding an error and return View. OR As Stephen suggested you can try [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) and going with Custom Validation attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the very easy and quite concise ExpressiveAnnotations JS library developed by Jaroslaw Waliszko. Follow this link to https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations for more information. This library allows you to perform different conditional validations. Similarly to Foolproof it is added to your Visual Studio environment through adding the NuGet package. Once added, within your model add the using statement using ExpressiveAnnotations.Attributes; Then simply use the AssertThat declaration to do what you need. For example:

```
[UIHint("ValuesModel")]
public ValuesModel LowValue { get; set; }

[UIHint("ValuesModel")]
[AssertThat("HighValue > LowValue", ErrorMessage = "Insert your error message here")]
public ValuesModel HighValue { get; set; }
```

Comment: I keep getting an error: assert that attribute validation applied failed

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder named Infrastructure (same level as Views, controllers etc).

Add a new class, LowHighCheck.cs

Use the code below to create your own validation attribute:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;

namespace YourNamespace.UI.Infrastructure
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class LowHighCheck : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private string[] PropertyList { get; set; }

        public LowHighCheck(params string[] propertyList)
        {
            this.PropertyList = propertyList;
        }

        public override object TypeId
        {
            get
            {
                return this;
            }
        }

        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            // integers for an example - if complex objects you'll need to 
            // perform some more operations to compare them here
            int low = (int)PropertyList.GetValue(1);
            int high = (int)PropertyList.GetValue(2);

            if (high < low)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Decorate your model with the attribute:

```
[LowHighCheck("LowValue", "HighValue", ErrorMessage = "your error message")]
public class YourViewModel
{
    //...
}
```

Remember to include the Infrastructure namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attributes from `DataAnnotations` namespace. It has `Compare` attribute. Usage: `[Compare("Field name to compare with", ErrorMessage = "Your Error Message")]`